# Use a method inside ViewController from ContainerView

Tags: swift, container-view

I have a ViewController, which have a containerView inside. So, I need to use a method in my ViewController from ContainerView.

I know how to use method in ContainerView from ViewController, but don't exactly know how to do the same conversely.

Big thanks for any help!

Comment: this is probably what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35440568/4286947

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send values to a parent view controller in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439041/how-to-send-values-to-a-parent-view-controller-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you, guys!!!